# How to use axios instead of ajax in datatable?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, datatable

I want to use axios to fetch data and load them to datatable. It is possible if I load all the data and render to datatable. But, what I want is load page number specific data. I don't want to load all the data at once it makes slow data loading. In short, I want to implement server side loading with axios in datatable. I have been stuck since long. Is there any way? Thanks.

Comment: What part are you struggling with? The Axios usage or backend implementation? Since you say you're struggling, please post a code example that someone can work with.

Comment: Please note that **axios** is a library which uses **AJAX**. You might want to rephrase the title of your question to: *"How to fetch server side rendered datatable by identifier of page using axios on a node server?"*

Comment: Yes, this is what I wanted to ask "How to fetch server-side rendered datatable by identifier of the page using axios on a node server?". That's what I described in my question. Sorry if it was confusing.

Answer (score 1):

Basically your front-end can ask the data as following with a start index and an end index as param in the url

```js
let myTable = document.querySelector('#myTable');

function fetchData(start, end) {
  let baseUrl = '/someData';
  let url =  `${baseUrl}?start=${start}&end=${end}`;

  axios({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/92rqu', // replace with url variable
  })
  .then( resp => {
    addTableRows(resp.data.data);
    currentStart += end - start;
  });
}

function addTableRows(data) {
  data.forEach( elem => {
    let tr = document.createElement('tr');
    [elem.firstName, elem.lastName, elem.age].forEach( txt => {
      let td = document.createElement('td');
      td.innerHTML = txt;
      tr.appendChild(td);
    });
    myTable.appendChild(tr);
  });
}

let currentStart = 0;

fetchData(currentStart, currentStart+5);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.19.0/axios.min.js" integrity="sha256-S1J4GVHHDMiirir9qsXWc8ZWw74PHHafpsHp5PXtjTs=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <th>first name</th>
    <th>last name</th>
    <th>age</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

and your back-end needs to read the start index and the end index to respond with the correct array of data.

In your front-end code you keep the track with the `currentStart` variable to trigger data fetching and table filling dynamically. Call `fetchData()` every time you want to see more rows.

Comment: Nice example but I think you need to intercept the datatable pagination events.

Comment: Can you divide above table to 2 pages i.e. 3 rows per page.

Comment: what do you mean by `per page` ?

Comment: I need to implement server side paging.

Comment: ok so start with posting your actual server side code